# Why is my iTunes link not opening in Chrome when user-agent is set to iOS?

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, google-chrome-devtools, itunes-store

I am developing a mobile web (jquery 1.7.1 and jquery mobile 1.1.0) application with a splash screen that encourages visitors to download the app.  There is a badge that says "Available on the App Store" if the user agent is an iOS browser, "Available in Google Play" if they're on an Android browser...you get the idea.

I am testing this in Chrome using developer tools to spoof the user agent, so I can test all the modes without needing actual devices.  When I'm in any mode except iOS everything works as expected.  Here's what I've observed in iOS user agent mode:

1) When the page loads, if I inspect the element with the link, everything looks fine:

```
<a id="appleStoreLink" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idXXXXXXXXX" class="ui-link">
<img class="storeBadgeImage" src="/images/App_Store_Badge.png" alt="iTunes download link">
</a>
```

2) When I click the badge link, nothing happens.  And look at what happens to my href (again I am seeing this by doing Inspect Element in chrome:

```
<a id="appleStoreLink" href="#" class="ui-link">
<img class="storeBadgeImage" src="/images/App_Store_Badge.png" alt="iTunes download link">
</a>
```

My version of Chrome is 23.0.1271.97 for Windows.

Comment: Sorry, but without code, we can't help you. Without that, I'm going to blame aliens. It's always aliens...

Comment: What code?  This is a plain old static HTML document.  I'm importing the jquery and jqm libs but not doing anything with them (on this page at least)

Comment: clicking on a link is NOT going to change a href in the html. there has to be something doing that, e.g. some javascript

Comment: I have more data.  I tried the same thing on a Mac.  When I click the link there it opens iTunes to my app page.

I did a curl GET on that iTunes URL and found quite a bit of javascript logic coming down.  In the end, it redirects to a custom url scheme that starts with itmss://.  More info about what that URL scheme is all about can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738175/launching-a-desktop-application-from-a-web-site/738205#738205

I believe that, since my PC does not have iTunes installed, it just silently dies.  The href suddenly becoming "#" issue is still unexplained.

Comment: Is it just me, or did this all begin with an update to Chrome for iOS that came down two or three months ago? This update I'm speaking of provided integration (ala intentions) between all Google apps on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct format for the link try this tool:[Link maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker)